# Reading in Complicated CSV to R

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to read in the following .csv file into R. As you can see from the imagine below, Row 2 has the unique variable names, while Row 3 has the values for the above variables. So Rows 2/3 together represent one observation. This process continues, so that Row 4 is a line of variable names and Row 5 corresponds to those variable values. This process continues so that each two-row pair (2/3, 4/5, 6/7....999/1000) represent one observation. There are 1,000 observations total in the data set.

What I am having trouble with is reading this into R so that I have a more usable dataset. My goal is to have a standard set of variable names across the top row, and each subsequent line representing one observation.

Any expert R coders have suggestions?

Thank you,

[image: CSV Image]

Comment: What have you tried? What makes this "complex"? Can you provide some examples of what you've done and what hasn't worked in the way you would have liked?

Comment: Read in one row as you column names, then read in all rowws with readLines, then read even number rows. Pretty sure this is a duplicate and a poorly presented one at that, since images are totally useless for constructing worked solutions.

Comment: Couldn't find duplicate but another strategy occurred, read in with read.csv and stringsAsFactors=FALSE and then drop every even number row (since the good data is now in the odd number rows because the header was created.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that worked on a simple test case I made. You'd need to import your data into a data.frame, `x = read.csv(file="your-file.csv")`

To test this though, I used the test data.frame, x:

```
x=structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"a", "ab", "h"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
4L, 3L), .Label = c("2", "b", "cd", "i"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("3", "a", "c", 
    "ef"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L
    ), .Label = c("4", "b", "d", "gh"), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("5", "c", "e", "ij"), class = "factor"), 
    V6 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("6", "d", "f", 
    "kl"), class = "factor"), V7 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L
    ), .Label = c("7", "e", "g", "mno"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Which turns this table (rows 1 and 3 are your labels):

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6  V7
1  a  b  c  d  e  f   g
2  1  2  3  4  5  6   7
3  h  i  a  b  c  d   e
4 ab cd ef gh ij kl mno
```

Using this script to generate a final data.frame `dat`:

```
library(plyr)
variables = x[seq(1,nrow(x),2),] #df of all variable rows
values = x[seq(2,nrow(x),2),] #df of all value rows
dat=data.frame() #generate blank data.frame
for(i in 1:nrow(variables)) {
    dat.temp=data.frame(values[i,])#make temporary df for the row i of your values
    colnames(dat.temp)=as.matrix(variables[i,]) # name the temporary df from row i of your variables
    print(dat.temp) #check that they are coming out right (comment this out as necessary)
    dat=rbind.fill(dat,dat.temp) #create the final data.frame
    rm(dat.temp) #remove the temporary df
}
```

Into this final table (variables are the column names now):

```
   a  b  c  d   e    f    g    h    i
1  1  2  3  4   5    6    7 <NA> <NA>
2 ef gh ij kl mno <NA> <NA>   ab   cd
```

Hope it works.